# Can I set a Up/Down/Left/Right shortcut with Esc + j/k/h/l in VS code for faster movements in code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

Using arrow keys while coding is very cumbersome. Learning Vim bindings will be helpful but I want to know is there a way to set shortcuts with combining two buttons(`Esc`+ other) just for the movements in Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: You can remap keys in PowerToys > Keyboard Manager. Under Shortcuts, add a shortcut like Ctrl + J, to Key "Down" etc

Comment: Actually, on second thought, just learn vim. It'll be worth it :)

Comment: For sure there is a vim plugin for vs code.